# How to find the duplicate email id and change to defaul id using trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I would like to create Contact in salesforce form my webpage. I would like to check the emaild and need to change before insert. if already exist.

**My In Complete Code**

```
trigger insertcontabct on Contact (before insert) {
List<String> emailAddresses = new List<String>();

// Get a list of the emails to check
for (Contact cont : trigger.new) {
    if(cont.Email != null){
        emailAddresses.add(cont.Email);
        System.debug('======='+emailAddresses);
    }
}
    List<Contact> contacts = [Select Email from Contact where Email IN : emailAddresses];

    if(!contacts.isEmpty()){

    ?????????????????????????????

    }
}
```

My Req : I want to check the email id. if exist need to create contact role or else create new contact. so how to do this?

Comment: Alex, it's not entirely clear what you want to change if the contact already exists (update the data ?) or what precisely you're having trouble with in terms of logic. Could you try to update the question with more info ?

Comment: I want to check the email id. if exist need to create contact role or else create new contact. so how to do this?

Comment: In a trigger you can use the addError method on the Email field of Contact when the Email address is already in use to add a message to that effect. This will stop the normal Save operation and present the error next to the field. The user can then either change the Email address or abandon the Save (and e.g. go and find the existing Contact that has that Email address). There is not much more you can do in a trigger. Is it code to do this that your require?